# Remove one of two divs if identical

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to remove one of two identical divs if they are side by side:

Example:

```
<div id="foo">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="foo2" href="/">Home</a></li>
        <div class="foo3"></div><div class="foo3"></div>
        <li><a class="foo2" href="link.html"><strong>Link text</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the above example two .foo3 links are present, while only one is needed.

Basically something like:

```
$("#foo ul li:contains('div.foo3 div.foo3')").first().remove();
```

Comment: Have you tried using the statement you posted? If so, did it work? If not, what's the error message in your JS console?

Comment: You know you oughtn't have a `div` child to a `ul` period, right?

Comment: You also have two `foo3` :)

Comment: Did you mean to remove `foo3` or `foo2`?

Comment: My bad I was meaning foo3

Comment: kojiro - passes w3c validation.. whats this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, Try

```
   $('div.foo3').eq(1).remove();
```

JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/rUvS5/1/

Comment: `div` selector is not needed in this case. Also, `eq` is not very fast: http://jsperf.com/eq-vs-last2

Comment: Cheers bud, this is spot on.

Comment: @Steve what happened if I have 4 divs with same class and I want remove second one? He has specified 2nd side by div only.

Comment: This would remove the 2nd div, but not any consecutive duplicates

Comment: @commit he is talking about only 2 divs: `one of two identical`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$('#foo ul li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('div.foo3').length > 1)
        $(this).find('div.foo3:not(:first)').remove();
});
```

Also, your `.foo3`s aren't in an `li`, they're in the `ul`.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j3MgT/1/)**

Comment: Yeah I just tried checking and your'e right. But I won't go deep as about 3 other better options have been suggested after mine

Comment: @stackErr wait, that's because your div isn't in an li, it's in the ul.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were the OP, so I addressed you by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;
$(".foo2").each(function() {
if (i >= 1){
    $(this).remove();
}     
 i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for something like `.each()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)) or `.filter()` if you have a clue how to select all but the first element. ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)).

```
$('#foo ul li div.foo3').each( function( i, elem ) {
  if( i != 0 ) {
    $(elem).remove();
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
$('.foo3').last().remove();
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/PPBt2/1/